# Covering the face of a dead person

Tags: halacha, minhag, death, funeral-burial-levaya, face

It appears to me that many Jews are careful to cover the face of a dead person as soon as the person dies. What is the reason for this? Is there a halacha that requires this? Or is it just a minhag? What is the source for this idea?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45011/why-do-we-close-the-eyes-of-the-deceased

Comment: See the 2nd answer in the above link.

Answer (score 3):

This is among the list of items Rambam enumerates as a *Minhag* while burying people.

Avel 4

> מִנְּהַג יִשְׂרָאֵל בְּמֵתִים וּבִקְבוּרָה כָּךְ הוּא. מְאַמְּצִין עֵינָיו שֶׁל מֵת. וְאִם נִפְתַּח פִּיו קוֹשְׁרִין אֶת לְחָיָיו. וּפוֹקְקִין אֶת נְקָבָיו אַחַר שֶׁמְּדִיחִין אוֹתוֹ. וְסָכִין אוֹתוֹ בְּמִינֵי בְּשָׂמִים. וְגוֹזְזִין שְׂעָרוֹ. וּמַלְבִּישִׁין אוֹתוֹ תַּכְרִיכִין תְּפוּרִין בְּחוּט שֶׁל פִּשְׁתָּן לְבָנִים. וְלֹא יִהְיוּ דְּמֵיהֶן יְקָרִים. וְנָהֲגוּ חֲכָמִים בְּסוּדָר שְׁוֵה זוּז שֶׁלֹּא לְבַיֵּשׁ אֶת מִי שֶׁאֵין לוֹ. **וּמְכַסִּין פְּנֵי הַמֵּת שֶׁלֹּא לְבַיֵּשׁ אֶת הָעֲנִיִּים** שֶׁפְּנֵיהֶם מֻשְׁחָרִין בָּרָעָב:

[Yoreh Deah 353](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De%27ah.353.1)

> בראשונה היו מגלים פני עשירים ומכסים פני עניים מפני שמשחירים בשנת בצורת והיו עניים חיים מתביישים התקינו שיהיו מכסים פני הכל:
>
> Formerly, they used to uncover the face of the rich [dead] and cover the face of the poor [dead] because their faces [i.e., of the poor dead] turned black in years of dearth and the surviving poor [near-of-kin] felt ashamed; hence, they ordained that one should cover everyone's face.1M.K. 27a. Cf. ibid. for other customs which were in vogue formerly but were changed later out of respect to those who would suffer embarrassment. Once the corpse is placed in the coffin and covered one must not open it in order to view the body — Kol Bo(G) I, p. 36.